# Flutter Dynamic Tab bar with Firestore data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, tabbar

Initially getting this error, but it fixed after few seconds.

The following assertion was thrown building TabBarView(dirty, dependencies: [_TabControllerScope], state: _TabBarViewState#5d34a):
The controller's length property (0) does not match the number of tabs (3) present in TabBar's tabs property.

The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView

This is my code.

```
class HomeTopTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomeTopTabsState createState() => _HomeTopTabsState();
  }

class _HomeTopTabsState extends State<HomeTopTabs>
          with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 TabController _tabController;
 List<Tab> tabs = [];
 int tabCount = 0;

 final CollectionReference categoryCollection =
  Firestore.instance.collection('categories');

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();

  _getCategoryTabs();

  // print(tabs.length);
  // print(tabCount);
}

@override
 void dispose() {
_tabController.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

void _handleTabSelection() {
setState(() {});
}


Future<void> _getCategoryTabs() async {
await categoryCollection.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.documents.isNotEmpty) {
    List<Tab> _tabs = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.documents.length; i++) {
      DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.documents[i];
      _tabs.add(
        Tab(
          child: Text(
            snap.documentID,
            // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      print(_tabs.length.toString() + "inner");
      tabCount = _tabs.length;
      tabs = _tabs;
    });

    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabCount);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }
});
```

}

Tab Bar

```
 TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            indicatorWeight: 0.1,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.orange,
            tabs: tabs)
```

**Whole code....**

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  // ignore: must_be_immutable
  class HomeTopTabs extends StatefulWidget {
    _HomeTopTabsState createState() => _HomeTopTabsState();
  }

  class _HomeTopTabsState extends State<HomeTopTabs>
      with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    TabController _tabController;
    List<Tab> tabs = [];
    int tabCount = 0;
    // List<String> str = ["a", "b", "c"];
    final CollectionReference categoryCollection =
        Firestore.instance.collection('categories');

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      _getCategoryTabs();

      // print(tabs.length);
      // print(tabCount);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _tabController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    void _handleTabSelection() {
      setState(() {});
    }

    Future<void> _getCategoryTabs() async {
      await categoryCollection.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.documents.isNotEmpty) {
          List<Tab> _tabs = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.documents.length; i++) {
            DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.documents[i];
            // tabCount++;
            _tabs.add(
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  snap.documentID,
                  // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          setState(() {
            print(_tabs.length.toString() + "inner");
            tabCount = _tabs.length;
            tabs = _tabs;
            _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabCount);
            _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
          });
        }
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return DefaultTabController(
        length: tabCount,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF263238),
          appBar: AppBar(
              leading: null,
              elevation: 0.0,
              // titleSpacing: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF263238),
              title: Text("Top Categories"),
              bottom: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicatorWeight: 0.1,
                  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                  labelColor: Colors.orange,
                  tabs: tabs
                  /*
              [
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Indian Recipe',
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Thai Recipe',
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Indian Recipe',
                  ),
                ),
                // Tab(
                //   child: Text(
                //     'Indian Recipe',
                //   ),
                // ),
                // Tab(
                //   child: Text(
                //     'Indian Recipe',
                //   ),
                // ),
              ],*/
                  )),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: CustomList(),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: CustomList(),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: CustomList(),
              ),
              // Container(
              //   height: 150.0,
              //   child: CustomList(),
              // ),
              // Container(
              //   height: 150.0,
              //   child: CustomList(),
              // ),
              // Container(
              //   height: 150.0,
              //   child: CustomList(),
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class CustomList extends StatelessWidget {
    const CustomList({
      Key key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final List<String> imgList = [
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
      ];

      final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
          .map((item) => Container(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0.0,
                          left: 0.0,
                          right: 0.0,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [
                                  Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                                  Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                ],
                                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                end: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Recipe By Priyanka',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList();

      return ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: imageSliders,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370556/return-async-value-to-initstate this given link will help you to set controller length.

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate any controller in initState

so try to make that your StatefullWidget

void initState() {
_tabController = TabController();
....
}

Comment: When I try to initiate the controller directly in initState, the error doesn't go away...

Comment: Try again with setState and  TabController(vsync: this, length: tabslenght); and be sure that the length is equal to number of tabs .. if it's not it will give you the same error

Comment: it's not working, I have no idea why tabs.length != number of tabs

Comment: Firat .. retun the tabs [ ] that you commented .. second @override
    void initState() { seState((){_tabController =TabController(vsync: this, length: 5); })
      super.initState();

 
    } Confirm that you initiate _tabController like that

Comment: If I hardcoded the tabs then there is no issue, I have to show the tabs according to the category in firestore. Basically  I'm showing a horizontal list for each category.