# Return async value to initState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I've the below code that is working fine, reading the csv data from url and printing the output:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  print(rowsAsListOfValues);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUserData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // ... // }
}
```

Instead of getting the output printed, I need it to be returned into a variable, which I can display in y widget, I tried to do it as below:

```dart
Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {   /// change
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }

  return rowsAsListOfValues;    /// change
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var rowsAsListOfValues;  /// new

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rowsAsListOfValues = fetchUserData();    /// new
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);   /// new
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // ... // }
}
```

But I got the output as `I/flutter ( 7505): Instance of 'Future<List<List<dynamic>>>'`

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: `initState` cannot be marked async. You can, however, start an async function (without awaiting it), then set the state inside that function once the underlying async operation has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch from initState to didChangeDependency in this case. Because you need to await some process and you cant wait in initState. However you can wait like this

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() async {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
  super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
  /// new
  print(rowsAsListOfValues);
}
```

And this is the result

```
I/flutter (24313): [[vranches], [Dammam, 2], [Khobar, 3]]
```

Comment: You can add setState((){}); after await so when it fetches data it setState the correct data

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code with Future.delayed() as given below.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,()async{
       rowsAsListOfValues =await fetchUserData();   
       setState(() {});
       print(rowsAsListOfValues);   // this return correct value
    });
   print(rowsAsListOfValues);  // this return null
  }
```

Full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _AppState extends State<HomePage> {
  var rowsAsListOfValues;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
      setState(() {});
      print(rowsAsListOfValues);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$rowsAsListOfValues',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got `I/flutter ( 7505): null`

Comment: console the value.

Comment: print the value of the rowsAsListOfValues

Comment: This is the one that gave me `null`

Comment: Bro here i am geeting data as I/flutter (10842): [[ches], [Dammam, 2], [Khobar, 3]]

Comment: With your code, I'm getting: `MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.`

Comment: Please use this App widget in home of your material app.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now why it returned `null` I was calling it outside the `async` scope.

Comment: I believe `async` is not allowed on `initState` to prevent the use of Futures during component initialization. Your code `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, ...)` simply hacks over that error check.

Answer (score 1):

The `initState` method is synchronous, and does not support `async`. I recommend the use of [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), but you can also move the code to an `async` function.

#### FutureBuilder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show
  Widget, FutureBuilder, AsyncSnapshot
;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static Future<void> fetchUserData() {
    return Future().delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      () => 'loaded'
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([
        fetchUserData()
      ]),

      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot snapshot
      ) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        }
        return Text('loading...');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

#### Async function

```dart
@override
void initState () {
  super.initState();
  (() async {
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);
  })();
}
```

OR

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initLoad();
}

void initLoad() async {
  rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
  print(rowsAsListOfValues);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel more relaxed when using `then()` with `async` functions. You can try this:

```
  

    fetchUserData().then((value) {
       setState(() {
        rowsAsListOfValues = value;
       });
    });
```

Or you can use `await` like this.

```
  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();

    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
                      
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);  
  }
```

Comment: The `.then()` option worded fine, the `await` option gave `_MyHomePageState.initState() returned a Future.`

Comment: Don't forget to use `async` in `inintState`:

void initState() `async` {

Comment: I did, I can not see `setState(() {});` where shall we use it?

Comment: There is an explanation about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373017/10659482